# Convert OpenISO8583.Net into different formats

Tags: c#-4.0, iso8583, openiso8583.net

I'm trying to implement an ISO8589 message to a financial institution.  They however, have a Web Service that I call and then I load the ISO8589 payload into an appropriate field  of the WCF service.

I have created an ISO8589 message this way:

```
var isoMessage = new OpenIso8583.Net.Iso8583();
isoMessage.MessageType = Iso8583.MsgType._0100_AUTH_REQ;
isoMessage.TransactionAmount = (long) 123.00;
isoMessage[Iso8583.Bit._002_PAN] = "4111111111111111";
// More after this.
```

I can't seem to figure out how I can convert the isoMessage into an ASCII human readable format so I can pass it through to the web service.

Anyone have any idea how this can be done with this library?  Or am I using this library the wrong way?

Thanks.

**UPDATED:**

I have figured out how to do this doing:

```
var asciiFormatter = new AsciiFormatter();
var asciiValue = asciiFormatter.GetString(isoMessage.ToMsg());
```

*However*, Now I am trying to take the isoMessage and pass the entire thing as hex string easily using OpenIso8583.Net, as follows:

```
var isoMessage = new OpenIso8583Net.Iso8583();
isoMessage.MessageType = Iso8583.MsgType._0800_NWRK_MNG_REQ;
isoMessage[Iso8583.Bit._003_PROC_CODE] = "000000";
isoMessage[Iso8583.Bit._011_SYS_TRACE_AUDIT_NUM] = "000001";
isoMessage[Iso8583.Bit._041_CARD_ACCEPTOR_TERMINAL_ID] = "29110001";
```

I know this is tricky, because some fields are BCD, AlpahNumeric, Numeric, etc. however, this should be realively easy (or I would think) using OpenIso8583.Net?  The result I'd like to get is:

```
Msg   Bitmap (3, 11, 41)      ProcCode Audit    Terminal ID
----- ----------------------- -------- -------- -----------------------
08 00 20 20 00 00 00 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 32 39 31 31 30 30 30 31
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you need to extend `Iso8583` which you initialise with your own `Template`  In the `Template`, you can set the formatters for each field so that BCD and binary packing is not used.  Have a look at the source code for `Iso8583` as to how it works.

Comment: You can download it from the public repo https://code.google.com/p/openiso8583net/source/list